# LibVLC v3.0.3 - How to know what are the only plugins needed by my application?

Tags: plugins, static, vlc, libvlc, lib

I am using LibVLC v3.0.3 for my application to play WAV sounds from memory.

So far I was able to determine the main plugin folders needed for this (and this is by only testing by deleting one folder at a time and test if the application is working and there is sound in the output).

I want to filter these 5 left folders which are (**access**, **audio_filter**, **audio_output**, **codec** and **demux**) to keep only the needed plugin **DLLs**.

I found out that: the less plugins are loaded, the more the application loads faster.

And, is it possible to link these plugin libraries statically with the application in the compile time !?

Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> How to know what are the only plugins needed by my application?

That would depend on what your application is doing. Once you know the features of your application, you can learn about [which VLC plugins do what](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:VLC_Modules_Loading/) and possibly remove those you do not want using `configure` if you build yourself https://wiki.videolan.org/Configure/.

> I found out that: the less plugins are loaded, the more the application loads faster.

I guess that's true, but not all plugins are loaded by default.

> And, is it possible to link these plugin libraries statically with the application in the compile time !?

Depends for which platform. For Windows I don't think so, but current VLC apps for Apple platforms are statically linked.

I'd advise you to have a look at the official apps build scripts from the VideoLAN gitlab https://code.videolan.org/explore/projects/starred

If by any chance you're using the .NET stack (for Windows), that will be easier thanks to https://github.com/mfkl/libvlc-nuget/blob/master/cherry-picking.md